# SQL Query to check if a date doesn't exist between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I work with a database that contains several days of a schedule.

I make requests to find possible errors.

I would like a query that checks the days. If a day of the period (startDate / endDate) is missing, I would like to know.

For exemple, if i my column "Day" in database contain :

```
01/01/2019
01/02/2019
01/04/2019
```

Is it possible to make a query that would look like this:

```
SELECT Day FROM Schedule WHERE Day doesn't exist BETWEEN 01/01/2019 AND 01/04/2019
```

I would like it to return to me 01/03/2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to use your [calendar table](http://web.archive.org/web/20170820091319/http://blog.jontav.com/post/9380766884/calendar-tables-are-incredibly-useful-in-sql), if you don't have one, then create one. They are very useful. Your query is then as simple as:

```
-- DUMMY DATA
WITH Schedule (Day) AS (SELECT CONVERT(DATE, D) FROM (VALUES ('20190101'), ('20190102'), ('20190104')) x (D))

SELECT  Date
FROM    dbo.Calendar AS c
WHERE   c.Date >= '20190101'        -- ADD A START DATE THAT SUITS YOUR NEEDS
AND     c.Date < '20190105'         -- ADD AN END DATE THAT SUITS YOUR NEEDS
AND     NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    Schedule AS s
            WHERE   s.Day = c.Date
        );
```

If you don't want to, or can't create a calendar table you can still do this on the fly pretty easily:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2019-01-01',
        @EndDate DATE = GETDATE();

WITH N1 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) n (N)),
N2 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N1 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N2),
N3 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N2 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N2 AS N2),
Dates AS
(   SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
            Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N) - 1, @StartDate)
    FROM N3
)
SELECT  *
FROM    Dates;
```

This will simply produce a list of all dates within the given date range. For further reading on this see:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 1](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 2](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 3](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3)

You would then just need to exclude rows where a schedule exists for that date:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '20190101',
        @EndDate DATE = '20190105';

WITH N1 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) n (N)),
N2 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N1 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N2),
N3 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N2 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N2 AS N2),
Dates AS
(   SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
            Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N) - 1, @StartDate)
    FROM N3
),
-- DUMMY DATA
Schedule (Day) AS (SELECT CONVERT(DATE, D) FROM (VALUES ('20190101'), ('20190102'), ('20190104')) x (D))

SELECT  *
FROM    Dates AS d
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    Schedule AS s
            WHERE   s.Day = d.Date
        );
```

**OUPUT**

```
Date
----------
2019-01-03
2019-01-05
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible(with calendar table or ad-hoc query to generate it):

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT CAST('20190101' AS DATETIME) t
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t + 1 AS t
  FROM cte
  WHERE t < '20190104'
)
SELECT c.*
FROM cte c
LEFT JOIN Schedule s
  ON c.t = s.[day]
WHERE s.[day] IS NULL;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ff020ad4b13db72a89209a6fd8473d16)**

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

1.- get the number of days between 2 dates:

```
 Set @numberofdays = DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate)
```

2.- get the number of days that are on the database between those dates and compare it

```
if @numberofdays == (select count(distinct(day)) from schedule where days>=@Startdate and days<=@EndDate)
print N'ok'
else
print N'days are missing'
```

that's in case that you only want to know if there are missing dates, in case that you do need to know which ones are those you can do

```
else  
set @currentday = @StartDate
while @currentday < @EndDate
begin
if (select day from schedule where day=@currentday == null)
print @currentday
DATEADD(day, 1, @currentday)
end
```

Comment: It is not clear to me if you only need to know that there are errors or that what is actually missing